# Is the solution of the stochastic heat equation a Gaussian process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations, parabolic-pde, stochastic-pde

We know that [the solution of a linear SDE is a Gaussian process](https://ethz.ch/content/dam/ethz/special-interest/mavt/dynamic-systems-n-control/idsc-dam/Lectures/Stochastic-Systems/SDE.pdf#page=40). I wonder whether the same is true for a SPDE casted to an infinite-dimensional SDE on a Hilbert space $H$ like $${\rm d}X_t=f(t)AX_t+\sigma W_t\tag1,$$ where $A$ is a (possibly unbounded) operator on $H$, $f:[0,T]\to\mathbb R$ and $W$ is a cylindrical Wiener process on $H$. The example that I've god in mind is $H=L^2(D)$, where $D\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ is bounded and open, and $A=\Delta u$ on $H^2(D)$. Assuming $X_0$ is deterministic or Gaussian, can we show that $X$ is then a Gaussian process? (In the sense of the Gaussian distribution on Hilbert spaces: http://www.kevinoconnor.co/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/GaussianMeasuresOnHilbertSpaces.pdf)?

We cannot simply mimic the proof from finite-dimensions, since here $A$ is not defined on all of $H$ ...

Comment: There is a bit of asymmetry between the title and the body. If I have understood correctly you are asking if the solution of a linear SDE is a Gaussian process. The stochastic heat equation is $$\partial_t u= \Delta u + \sigma(u) \xi$$ where $\xi$ is the white noise and $\sigma$ is an operator (plus eventually some not linear term)

Comment: @Marco I'm interested in the SDE in eq. (1). The heat equation you stated is the case $A=\Delta$, $f=1$ and my $\sigma$ does not depend on $u$ (since in that case the solution process is clearly not Gaussian in general). So, maybe I should write [diffusion equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffusion_equation) instead of ]heat equation in the title.

Comment: For the (additive) heat equation, by Duhamel's principle you have that $$u=\int_{\mathbb{R^3} \times [0,t]} K(t-s,x-y)  d\xi(dy,ds)$$ where $K$ is the heat kernel. As the heat kernel is a gaussian kernel, I'm pretty sure that in that case is Gaussian. I doubt this is the case for a general diffusion, but I'm not sure about it

Comment: @Marco I guess you are assuming that your $u$ is the solution of your stochastic heat equation? Why doesn't $\sigma$ show up there? Also: Could you clarify your notation? I don't get what $\xi({\rm d}y,{\rm d}s)$ means here. I'm not interested in general stochastic forcing so that you can assume $\xi=W$. Do you then mean that $u(t)=\int_0^t\int K(t-s,x-y)\:{\rm d}W_s(y)\:{\rm d}s$? How do I need to understand this? The Wiener process in infinite-dimension is only defined as an equivalence class. So pointwise evaluation seems to be probablematic.

Comment: I'm not interested in general diffusion. I only want to generalize your equation slightly by introducing $f$. That is, my eq. is then $\partial_tu=f(t)\Delta u(t)+\sigma\xi$.

Comment: @Maro Oh, and last question: Did you notice that my equation is on the bounded domain $D$? (I'm mostly interested in $D=(0,1)^2$). Is that a problem? I'm also assuming Neumann boundary.

Comment: The boundness of the domain is usefull if you are not assuming periodic boundary condition (otherwise you ca have some blow up of the solution). $\xi$ is actually to be intended as a distribution valued R.V- such that $$\mathbb{E}[(\xi, \eta_1) (\xi,\eta_2)]=\int \eta_1(x,s) \eta_2(x,s) dx ds$$ for any $\eta_1,\eta_2$ Schwarz function. The pointwise notation is actually an abuse of notation, but you are right, it does not make sense. It has to be understood as a stochastic integral (see [this](https://hairer.org/) notes). I want to clarify that I am by no means an expert on the field

Comment: @Marco is correct. The equation is linear and so the solution is a linear function of the Gaussian noise $W$. Thus it is Gaussian itself.

Comment: @almosteverywhere (a) But it's only Gaussian when $X_0$ is Gaussian (or constant), isn't it? (b) Do you think we can show that the distribution of $X_t$ converges to some equilibrium (Gaussian) distribution?

Comment: (a)Yes that is correct. (b) Yes, that should be possible but it depends on what you assume on $f(t)$?

Comment: @almosteverywhere I'm willing to assume that it is linear: $f(t)=at+b$

Comment: @almosteverywhere I got some doubts. $W$ in the question is a *cylindrical* Wiener process. That means that not even $W_t$ is a Gaussian on $H$; only on a larger space.

Comment: Yes, that makes no difference. The solution operator maps $W$ from a larger space to $H$ and is linear, i.e. assume $f(t)=\mathrm{const}$ for convenience, then $X(t)=e^{t\Delta} X_0 + \int_0^t e^{(t-s)\Delta}dW_t$. Here $\int_0^t e^{(t-s)\Delta}dW_t$ maps $W_t$ is linear map from the space $W$ lives in to $H$ and so the resulting object is Gaussian on $H$.

Comment: @almosteverywhere Sorry, that was a stupid question. The integral wrt to $W$ already needs integrands which are Hilbert-Schmidt from $U$ ($=H$ here; the space where $W$ is taking values in) to $H$. From this it's already clear that a strong solution takes values in $H$.